# Good practice on selecting a list menu

Tags: css, list, selector

Considering this markup:

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="mainmenu">
     <ul>
      <li> <a href=""><h1>My Dashboard</h1></a></li><br>
      <li> <a href=""><h1>About</h1></a></li><br>
      <li> <a href=""><h1>Contact</h1></a></li><br>
      <li> <a href=""><h1>Setttings</h1></a></li><br>
      <li> <a href=""><h1>Log Out</h1></a></li><br>
     </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Selecting this way is a valid thing? I am having issues with some properties.

```
#container ul li{
    display: inline-block;

}


#mainmenu ul li a{}

#mainmenu ul li a:hover{}
```

full sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/jhr1q1q4/

Comment: #mainmenu a {} should be enough?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include what properties you are having issues with. There is no CSS in those selectors.

Comment: You need to provide accurate code. i.e. inside the brackets to properly debug it.

Comment: are just style stuff, nothing relevant: my main concern is about how to properly select those items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm somewhat unsure what you're asking...

Strictly speaking, the selectors you provided are valid and would select the `<a>` elements within your `#mainmenu` element.

But I would ask: is the `ul li` part of the selectors necessary? You could rewrite both of them as

```
#mainmenu a {}
#mainmenu a:hover {}
```

and they would work the same and require less parsing. If you wanted to only select `<a>` elements that are descendants of `<li>` elements, you could keep the `li` in your selector; however, the `ul` is not necessary -- it is implied your `<li>` elements will be children of a `<ul>` (assuming you're writing valid HTML).

Another note: `<a>` elements are *inline*, meaning they're meant to act at the text level. `<h1>` elements, on the other hand, are block-level elements, and thus do not belong inside `<a>` elements. In fact, you usually shouldn't have more than one `<h1>` on a page, let alone be using `<h1>`'s to mark up menu items. If you want your menu items to be big like headers, use your CSS rules to style them that way.

> I am having issues with some properties.

What properties are causing trouble?

Comment: These are nice talk - thanks. And nevermind about the issues I was having, those was caused by other mal functions. Thanks.